# Perl for loop error

Tags: arrays, perl, perl-data-structures

I am new to the Perl, I was trying to execute a simple program as encoded below using Strawberry perl 5, version 16:

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @array= {1,2,3,5,7,9};
my $i;

foreach $i (@array)
{
print qq(Element is $i\n);
}
```

I am getting the below as output:

```
Element is HASH(0x3f8b4c)
```

However the output that I should receive is:

```
Element is 1
Element is 2
Element is 3
Element is 5
Element is 7
Element is 9.
```

Appreciate your help in this.

Answer (score 10):

To initialize an array, use a *list* like

```
my @array = (1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 9);
```

Note: The parens just sort out the precedence, they are not a special array syntax.

Curlies delimit an anonymous hashref, like

```
my $foobar = {
  foo => "bar",
  baz => "qux",
};
```

So what happened is that you assigned to your array a list of one anonymous hashref, just like

```
my @array = ({
  1 => 2,
  3 => 5,
  7 => 9,
})
```

would have worked.

Comment: But you shouldn't ever do the latter initialization. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @array= (1,2,3,5,7,9);

foreach my $i (@array)
{
print "Element is ", $i,"\n"; ##Or as u want..many ways to do things in perl
}
```

Try like this. The array should be in parenthesis. Curly braces to be used in hashes.

Comment: Curly braces are used to look-up data in hashes. Hashes are initialised using round brackets - in exactly the same way as arrays.

Answer (score 0):

you should use () to define an array instand of {},{} is used to defind a hash

```
#!usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

my @array= (1,2,3,5,7,9);
my $i;

foreach $i (@array)
{
  print qq(Element is $i\n);
}
```

Comment: Not really. The round brackets are used to create a list, not an array. Both arrays and hashes can be initialised from lists.